# Removing parameters in Stripe API versioning

Tags: api

[This](https://stripe.com/blog/api-versioning) blog post laid out an interesting API versioning system used at Stripe that has high developer productivity with backwards compatibility of API.

It gives an easy example of an API change which changes the name of a parameter. How would this work if one were to **remove** a parameter in a new API version? It seems then if the core codebase creates a response without this parameter according to the latest version, it may not be able to produce it when it goes through the compatibility gates.